# Acts_as_commentable_with_threading - comments are not adding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-commentable

@post.comments.all is clear. and i dont see any errors after i send form. When i click "Submit" i sent to posts/id/comments, but

my routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

post controller

```
  def show
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    @commenter = @current_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.build_from( @post, @commenter.id, "234234" )
    @comments = Comment.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @comments = @post.comments.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new params[:comment]
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post # comment not save, so i dont redirect to this page
    else
      # is that there
    end
  end

end
```

post model

```
  acts_as_commentable
  has_many :comments
```

comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  attr_accessible :commentable, :body, :user_id
  validates :body, :presence => true
  validates :user, :presence => true

  # NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
  # want user to vote on the quality of comments.
  #acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  # NOTE: Comments belong to a user
  belongs_to :user

  # Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
  # by passing a commentable object, a user_id, and comment text
  # example in readme
  def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)

    new \
      :commentable => obj,
      :body        => comment,
      :user_id     => user_id
  end

  #helper method to check if a comment has children
  def has_children?
    self.children.any?
  end

  # Helper class method to lookup all comments assigned
  # to all commentable types for a given user.
  scope :find_comments_by_user, lambda { |user|
    where(:user_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  # Helper class method to look up all comments for
  # commentable class name and commentable id.
  scope :find_comments_for_commentable, lambda { |commentable_str, commentable_id|
    where(:commentable_type => commentable_str.to_s, :commentable_id => commentable_id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  # Helper class method to look up a commentable object
  # given the commentable class name and id
  def self.find_commentable(commentable_str, commentable_id)
    commentable_str.constantize.find(commentable_id)
  end
end
```

post view

```
%h2 Add a comment:
- @comments.each do |c|
  = @c.body
= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f|

  .field
    = f.label :body
    %br/
    = f.text_area :body
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can debug why `@comment.save` return false yourself - just add `p @comment.errors` in else block and check server log.

It seems for me that you try to save invalid comments because you don't have setup `user` for `@comment` in action `CommentsController#create`. **Comment validates presence of user!**

There are several ways how to fix it. Analyzing your code I think the simplest way for you is modify `CommentsController#create`

```
#CommentsController
def create
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new params[:comment]
  @comment.user = @current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post # comment not save, so i dont redirect to this page
  else
    # is that there
  end
end
```

Another way is to use some gem for authentication - I recommend [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

One more way (**very bad way**) is to pass user_id through hidden field (you have defined `@current_user` in `PostsController#show` and user_id in attr_accessible list in Comment). But this is easy way to hack your application and write comments on behalf of any user in system!